# How to extract a particular text from url in jQuery

Tags: jquery, string, url

i'm newbie in jQuery.

I have a url like

```
http://example.com/test/the-apartment/tomt-7-1-103-5-kvm-bra
```

I would like to cut `tomt-7` and remove `-`. The final result should be: `tomt7`

Comment: [StackOverflow isn't here to do your work for you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Show us what you have tried so far. We'll gladly help you.

Answer (score 3):

This should give you the desired result:

```
var str = "http://example.com/test/the-apartment/tomt-7-1-103-5-kvm-bra"
var last = str.split('/');
last = last[last.length -1];

var result = last.split('-').slice(0,2).join("");
```

**Demo**

```js
var str = "http://example.com/test/the-apartment/tomt-7-1-103-5-kvm-bra"
var last = str.split('/');
last = last[last.length -1];

var result = last.split('-').slice(0,2).join("");

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much